# Remove `-` character at the end of domain name

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

I have this code:

```
string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,\\]/g,'');
```

I want to remove all invalid characters from domain. It's working fine, but additionally I want to remove `-` character from the end if it is here.

So, `te-!#$#@$@#st-.com` will be `te-st.com`.

I tried added something like that `[-]$`, so the code looks like this:

```
string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&`*()_\+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,\\][-]$/g,'')
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I tried it and it's actually working fine.. 1st regex.

Comment: You can think so, but it's removing all `-` characters, but i want to remove only at the end if it is here.

Comment: so my code return `test.com`, but it should return `te-st.com`

Comment: Why you would want to complicate your regex that way? If you just remove `-$` using a separate regex then your code would remain readable. I mean, if it has to be explained to you, then imagine the next developer coming along... `remove_invalid_chars()` and `remove_trailing_dash()` make for very readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an alternation here:

```
string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&`*()_\+={}[\]|"':;?,\/><,\\]|-+(?=\.)/g, '')
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

- `[~!@#$%^&*()_\+={}[\]|"':;?,\/><,\\]` match a symbol
- `|` OR
- `-+(?=\.)` match 1 or more dashes which are followed by dot (but do not consume the dot)

Comment: What that group means `(?=\.)` at the end?

Comment: I have another problem here. If I type for example multiple `-` at the end `te-!#$#@$@#st-----.com` it will not remove all dashes from the end. Any solutions for that?

Comment: I have updated my answer with your new requirement.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for bothering you, but maybe you know how to remove all whitespaces too. I tried `\s`, but thats seems to not work.

Comment: Maybe you should stop changing your requirements?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I think that this is not that questions for adding new question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use replacer function:

```
const firstIndex = string.indexOf('-');
string.replace(/[~!@#$%^&*()_\-+={}[\]|"':;?,/><,\\]/g,
    (match,offset) => offset === firstIndex ? match : ''
);
```